# How do I set the path to DLL files in Visual Studio using bat file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, batch-file, dll

I have a bat (SetPath.bat) file which set the paths of the exe's dll dependency. I know that one can add individual path variables in VS proj properties->Debugging->Environment. But I want to avoid duplication. Is there any way I can refer to SetPath.bat in VS proj settings? OR any other solution that satisfies the intention of having single source of path dependency to run the exe inside and outside visual studio?

PS: I use the bat file to call the exe outside visual studio.

Comment: No.  There should be no duplication, only the environment of the exe project matters.  Avoid DLL Hell by using the exe project's post-build event to xcopy /d the dependencies.

Comment: I suggest that  you could insert your DLL directory in the %PATH% variable, and Windows will then find the DLL there. `set PATH=C:\path to your dll;%PATH%`

Answer (score 0):

The "single source" might be achieved by defining the ->Debugging->Environment properties in a single `.vsprops` file, and adding that to your projects,

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in the question. See PS (edit). I actually wanted to set dll path from a single source for both within and outside VS studio for exe execution